# API for Detecting Windows Active Directory name/IP

Tags: winapi, active-directory

I have a requirement to detect all users from local and Active Directory(if present) in Windows.

I have found that C API: `NetQueryDisplayInformation()` has also the option to retrieve the information from a "serverName", which is presumably an Active Directory which can be queried.

But how do I find out if ActiveDirectory is available/ and it's name ?
Thanks.

Comment: that's great info ! thanks. Managed also to look over MS WMI documentation and source code available on koders.com that used this class, Win32_ComputerSystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is available in WMI. In the [`Win32_ComputerSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102%28VS.85%29.aspx) class (there will be a single instance per computer) has a `Domain` property containing the domain's name.

Comment: that's great info ! thanks. Managed also to look over MS WMI documentation and source code available on koders.com that used this class, Win32_ComputerSystem

Answer (score 0):

Another way of finding out domain name (if present) is to use WIN API ::DsGetDcName()
This one returns information about Active Dir server name in DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO struct.
You get there all the domain information you need. Much sympler than using WMI :-)